# Is is possible to have grouped GridView without using CollectionViewSource?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

It is just seems to be a little awkward design to tie a feature to a class instead of interface. Has anybody managed to group GridView without CollectionViewSource?

Also a bonus question here: why you have to refer to the CollectionViewSource resource through binding:

```
    <GridView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedData}}"
        >
```

instead of

```
    <GridView
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource groupedData}"
        >
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use CollectionViewSource. All you need to do is create your own class with ICollectionView interface. Using CollectionViewSource would save you a lot of code though.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to implement your own, though... Most of the methods of ICollectionView are not used, anyway. Looking forward for somebody posting a CollectionViewSource replacement that would be easy to customize.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried for severals days to not use CollectionViewSource. Not because I think it is bad but I didn't know that you have to do this. It is IMO impossible to have groups and grouped items with out it. 
I don't know why (I guess when you read refs or see the code you'll understand) but you have to do this. When you put your grouped data to GridView you'll get the first level (groups only) but you won't be able to get to the items. Only be connecting it with CollectionViewSource you can have both